# Determining whether two two-digit numbers share a digit in common

Tags: java, programming-challenge

I have solved [a CodingBat problem](http://codingbat.com/prob/p153748): Given two ints, each in the range 10..99, return true if there is a digit that appears in both numbers, such as the 2 in 12 and 23. (Note: division, e.g. n/10, gives the left digit while the % "mod" n%10 gives the right digit.)

```
shareDigit(12, 23) → true
shareDigit(12, 43) → false
shareDigit(12, 44) → false
```

My working code is:

```
public boolean shareDigit(int a, int b) {
      boolean answer = false;
      int lefta = a/10;
      int righta = a % 10;
      int leftb = b/10;
      int rightb = b % 10;
      if(lefta == leftb || lefta == rightb || righta == leftb || righta == rightb){
        answer = true;  
      }
      return answer;
}
```

It feels extremely inefficient, and I was wondering if anyone could improve it.

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify the boolean parts of your method.

```
public boolean shareDigit(int a, int b) {
    int lefta = a / 10;
    int righta = a % 10;
    int leftb = b / 10;
    int rightb = b % 10;
    return lefta == leftb || lefta == rightb || righta == leftb
            || righta == rightb;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is efficient. You just do 4 comparisons. You cannot find answer with less. Maybe instead you can use:

```
if( (a/10)== (b/10)|| (a/10 )==( b % 10)||  (a % 10)== (b/10) ||  (a % 10) == (b % 10)){
    answer = true;  
}
```

Comment: Now *this* is inefficient!

Answer (score 0):

Usually when I see these types of questions that treat digits as tokens(is that the right word?) they typically specify not to use string manipulation. But it makes this problem much easier.

It's a bit harder to determine the Big O comparison since it uses external libraries. But we cut down the integer `a` to only it's unique digits (could also be done for `b` but in a two digit number doesn't save you much), and do only one comparison of each number so sort of `O(n)` vs matching each digit with every other digit `O(n^2)`

```
//Javascript, it was taking me too long to figure out Java
//But you get the gist, this also has the added benefit of
//Supporting any length number, and mismatched number lengths

// a = 12
// b = 23
function shareDigit (a, b){
     // setA = <'1', '2'>
     const setA = new Set(a.toString().split(''));
     // arrayB = ['2', '3']
     const arrayB = b.toString().split('');

     for(let i = 0; i < arrayB.length; i++) {
          if(setA.has(arrayB[i])){
               return true;
          }
      }
     return false;

}
```